# I am able to see user's password from input and axios requests inside a memory dump of a React Native Android application

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, security, axios

I'm using fridump to get a memory dump of my React Native Android application and I'm being able to see my password inside the memory dump.

First of all, I could go to the login screen, just type my password in the password input field without submitting and if I create a memory dump at that point, I can already see my password in the memory.

Secondly, if I submit my email and password, I can see the Axios post request payload that includes my email and password.

The password is not stored in the storage of the device, so it must be stored in the RAM of the device. My question is if it is even possible to somehow prevent the information from appearing in the memory dump?

Comment: You need adb access to do that, so i don't think it's an issue, i can do the same with chrome and retrieve the passwords, and also the device needs to be rooted to run the frida-server. The only thing you can do that can be useful is stealing api keys for example that might be in memory

Comment: How could things possibly work if the code in the client doesn't have the password in memory somewhere, at least while preparing the payload for a (secure) web transaction?

Comment: Is it possible for me to somehow clear the password from the memory after I've gone through the login steps, made the POST request to the back-end and have logged in? At that point I'd have the JWT token so I wouldn't need the password anymore, so it'd be safe to remove it from memory.

Comment: Good question. In the java world you can achieve this by storing a password in a char array (instead of a string), because the strings are immutable, but an array is not. A char array can be overridden with some values when the password is not needed any more, making a memory dump not show the secret. But honestly, I would not go that way. A memory dump will always show some secrets, be it tokens, cookies, whatever. You exchange a password for a something. Do you want to protect this something too?